# Fork incoming requests using python flask

Tags: python, networking, post, flask

I have developed a REST server using Flask in python and currently it is built in synchronous manner. next request is processed only after completion of existing request and sometimes this is increasing response time. Most of the processing is network dependent and takes few seconds. What are the best ways to handle ie fork so that I can handle multiple requests simultaneously.

```
@app.route('call', methods = ['POST'])
def create_task2():
    result = process(request) # takes around 5 seconds
    return jsonify( result  ), 201
```

When 2 request are sent to my restserver simultaneously, 2nd one has to wait for atleast 10 seconds before receiving the response. I want to use this as a restserver catering requests to external users

Comment: I suppose you're using the builtin webserver, not an external like gunicorn,...?

Comment: Yes I am building web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens only because you're using the development server included. Flask is a web framework, not a webserver.

Concurrent request serving is a task handled by webservers.

You can use a wsgi webserver like uWSGI to serve your flask application.
For even more performance you can also delegate static serving to NGINX but for a pure REST server normally is not needed.

With uWSGI you can specify the number of workers (processes) handling in parallel.

Keep in mind that there's no magic in serving a lot of requests.
Even if you use more processes or threads you're bound to that number of concurrent request handling.